# How to automatically switch monitors with my laptop dock

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, dock

I have a Dell Precision M4300 with a Dell Dock PRO1X running Ubuntu Natty.

When I have the laptop docked the lcd display is off and I use two external monitors however when I undock the laptop it does not switch to the laptop screen. The same happens when I dock the laptop, it does not switch to the external monitors.

If I reboot the laptop it will choose the correct setup but it will not automatically change monitors with Ubuntu running.

My [Xorg.conf](http://dpaste.com/hold/542434/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Dock/UnDock Scripts

I have finally put together a complete script setup that will detect my dock status and switch the monitors automatically.

The first thing I did was to get rid of my Xorg.conf as it caused more issues that it solved. Since I am using an nvdia card I eventually found that using ***[disper](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/)*** was the best way to go.  I had discounted it before as its standard commands could not achieve my dualview setup but then I found I could create a custom metamode to use with disper.

To create the custom metamode I used the values stored in Xorg.conf along with previous testing with ***nv-control-dpy*** and ***[xrandr](http://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR)*** as a guide. This metamode and other twinview values were added to a file that can be passed to disper through *stdin*.

Due to having different sized monitors with Twinview I need to use [XCreateMouseVoid](https://github.com/cas--/XCreateMouseVoid), as described in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48922/how-to-align-twinview-monitors-with-different-resolutions-and-prevent-mouse-disap).

Below is a complete breakdown of the  scripts and files with their contents.

---

### Scripts

1. Create XCreateMouseVoid script:

   Script Name: `~/.mousevoid`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "Mouse Void"
   /opt/XCreateMouseVoid/XCreateMouseVoid 0 1112 1280 88 &
   /opt/XCreateMouseVoid/XCreateMouseVoid 0 0 1280 88 &
   ```

   `chmod +x ~/.mousevoid`
2. Create Disper settings file:

   File Name: `~/.disperDocked`

   ```
   backend: nvidia
   associated displays: CRT-0, DFP-0, DFP-1
   metamode: CRT-0: 1280x1024_60 @1280x1024 +0+88, DFP-1: 1920x1200 @1920x1200 +1280+0
   scaling: default, default, stretched
   xinerama info order: DFP-1, CRT-0, DFP-0
   ```
3. Create the export dbus session script:

   Script Name: `~/.export_x_info`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Export the dbus session address on startup so it can be used by any other environment
   sleep 5
   touch $HOME/.Xdbus
   chmod 600 $HOME/.Xdbus
   env | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > $HOME/.Xdbus
   echo 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS' >> $HOME/.Xdbus
   # Export XAUTHORITY value on startup so it can be used by cron
   env | grep XAUTHORITY >> $HOME/.Xdbus
   echo 'export XAUTHORITY' >> $HOME/.Xdbus
   ```

   Set to user executable only: `chmod 700 ~/.export_x_info`

   Then put it in Startup Applications:

   ```
   Name: X Environment Variables
   Command: /home/your_user/.export_x_info
   ```

   Unless you restart you need to run ~/.export_x_info to create the *.Xdbus* file
4. Create the udev rule that will run with upon a dock event:

   Script Name: `/etc/udev/rules.d/81-dell-dock.rules`

   `KERNEL=="dock.0", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/dell-dock"`

   `chmod +x /etc/udev/rules.d/81-dell-dock.rules`
5. Create the script that is associated with the udev rule:

   Script Name: `/usr/local/sbin/dell-dock`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # wait for the dock state to change
   sleep 0.5
   DOCKED=$(cat /sys/devices/platform/dock.0/docked)
   case "$DOCKED" in
      "0")
          echo "Run UnDocking Script..."
           /usr/local/sbin/undock
           ;;
       "1") 
           echo "Run Docking Script..."
           /usr/local/sbin/dock
           ;;
   esac
   exit 0
   ```

   `chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/dell-dock`
6. Create the undock script (change *your_user* to match your user name):

   Script Name: `/usr/local/sbin/undock`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   USER=your_user
   export HOME=/home/$USER
   source $HOME/.Xdbus
   export DISPLAY=:0
   echo "UnDocking Script"
   echo "Switch primary monitor"
   sudo -u $USER disper -s
   echo "Killall XCreateMouseVoid"
   pkill XCreate
   echo "Restart conky"
   pkill conky
   sudo -u $USER conky &
   ```

   `chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/undock`
7. Create the dock script (change *your_user* to match your user name):

   Script Name: `/usr/local/sbin/dock`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   USER=your_user
   export HOME=/home/$USER
   source $HOME/.Xdbus
   export DISPLAY=:0
   echo "Docking Script"
   echo "Switch to Dualview"
   sudo -u $USER disper -i < $HOME/.disperDocked
   echo "Start XCreateMouseVoid"
   pkill XCreate
   sudo -u $USER $HOME/.mousevoid
   echo "Restart conky"
   pkill conky
   sudo -u $USER conky &
   ```

   `chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/dock`

---

### Debug

To debug the dock scripts you have to enable udev debug logging:

```
udevadm control --log-priority=debug
```

Then open ***syslog*** in **Log File Viewer**

---

### Resources

nVidia Readme: [Config Twinview](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/270.41.06/README/configtwinview.html), [X Config Options](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/270.41.06/README/xconfigoptions.html) 
[Autorandr](https://github.com/wertarbyte/autorandr)
[Disper PPA](https://launchpad.net/~wvengen/+archive/ppa)
[nv-control-dpy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=922956) 
[Ubuntu Forum - Un/Dock Scripts](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1076486)
[Thinkwiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Docking_Solutions)
[udevadm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/udevadm.8.html)

Comment: Cas, it was suggested that I comment on your post to ask about the problem that I am having with this:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/68737/auto-switching-with-dock

Comment: Do you have the script dell-dock.sh?

Comment: Yes it seems that that file does not exist:  `$ cat /sys/devices/platform/dock.0/docked
cat: /sys/devices/platform/dock.0/docked: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [autorandr](https://github.com/wertarbyte/autorandr).

> Auto-detect the connect display hardware and load the appropiate X11 setup using xrandr or disper
>
> Automatically select a display configuration based on connected devices

See also:

- [Using Autorandr for Undocking Goodness in Linux](http://rockycode.com/blog/using-autorandr-undocking-goodness/)
- [A tool for automatically applying RandR configuration when external display is plugged in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/a-tool-for-automatically-applying-randr-configuration-when-external-display-is-p/22462#22462)
- [How do I perform easy switching to external monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65257/how-do-i-perform-easy-switching-to-external-monitor/441776#441776)

Comment: This solution is painless and works great.