# 16.04 LTS Suspends after Resume from Hibernate

Tags: 16.04, laptop, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, hibernate

I hibernate with the lid open (docked or undocked).  I resume with the lid closed, and docked.  After logging in, the system will suspend (sleep) on its own, each and every time I attempt to resume.  Finally, I had to open the lid, resume, log in, and do a full shut down.  That, just so that I could close the lid when shut down and docked, and start up normally.  Are you kidding me?

Dell Latitude E6530
Intel Core i7-3540M
Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (Unrecognized by Ubuntu)
nVidia NVS 5200M (Optimus disabled in BIOS, unsupported!)

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing....

Comment: Looks like your best bet might be to have the system ignore the lid.  But then you would have to suspend manually with the power icon on the unity panel.

Comment: I just repeated this.  A clarification, would be, that I hibernated with the lid  open.  I resumed, with the lid closed, while on a docking station.  After logging in successfully, the system suspends (not hibernates) on its own.  Any attempt to resume from the suspended state follows an endless loop of resume, login, suspend, repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You system seems confused as to why you want don't want it to sleep when the lid is closed.  You can try disabling the feature that suspends the laptop when closing the lid.  The downside to this is that you'll have to suspend it manually.

Open a terminal and edit the logind.conf file using `gksudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`

Look for the line that says `HandleLidSwitch=`.

Change this line from whatever it is, to `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` and make sure it's not commented out (Make sure there's no # symbol before it).

Save and close the file.

Now back in terminal, run `sudo restart systemd-logind`.  You can also double-check the "Power" options in the control center to make sure nothing is telling it to sleep with the lid closed.

Try closing the lid, it should now do nothing.  Just make sure to remember to suspend it manually when you want it to by using the power menu in the top right corner of the screen, on the Unity panel.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed recommendation.  It sounds as if I have lost another basic feature that is available for Windows 7, now that I am running 16.04.  I do so miss being able to use the laptop screen and the two external monitors.  It is tough to lose ground with displays, either running Nouveau or nVidia.   And the Intel HD Graphics is not recognized.  Now I lose automatic sleep, it seems.

Comment: Yes unfortunately for those of us who love Linux, we sometimes have to work to get things done.  My answer should fix your suspend issue but as for your docking problem, you might want to look at [the answer to this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42741/how-to-automatically-switch-monitors-with-my-laptop-dock) to help you get started on fixing that.

Comment: Thanks for more ways that might help with docking issues.  I have the nVidia proprietary driver installed, which has this command:

`nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode`

The output from which looks like:

`$ nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode

  Attribute 'CurrentMetaMode' (and-d0013325:0.0): id=50, switchable=yes, source=RandR :: DPY-2: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080
  +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DPY-3: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080,
  ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}`

Comment: So a script can be made to toggle to that setting usiing the text after the ":::", such as :

`#!/bin/bash
nvidia-settings -a CurrentMetaMode="DPY-2: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DPY-3: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have a dock or anything to try anything myself so you'll have to ask another separate question about that.  But I hope my answer solved your suspending problem.  And if it did please mark it as accepted and ask a new question about the docking and video issues.

Comment: XToro, thanks for the tips on logind.conf settings. I have seen the system behave more sanely, docked or undocked. Since there seems to be no way to use the laptop display as a third display, when docked, there is no need to have it open when docked, and thus no need to have the system sleep automatically when the laptop is shut. And s you note I do have to use the menu to sleep, even when undocked, rather than have that automatic feature enabled. This must be one of the reasons why Dell no longer provided support for Linux, directly.